# How do you set the pitch of a Mapbox map in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, maps, mapbox, mapbox-gl

Very new to using Mapbox, and having troubles setting the pitch/bearing of the mapView. Is there something like:

```
mapView.setPitch = 45
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way you can do it.

```
//Create a new MKMapCamera object
var newCameraPosition = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: mapView.centerCoordinate, fromDistance: mapView.camera.altitude + 1600, pitch: 50, heading: -30)

// Then you could call it like this
 mapView.camera = newCameraPosition
```

[MapBox MGLMapCamera](https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Classes/MGLMapCamera.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapCamera(cm)cameraLookingAtCenterCoordinate:fromDistance:pitch:heading:)

But let me elaborate for the setup.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MGLMapView!

let distance: CLLocationDistance = 500
let pitch: CGFloat = 35
let heading = 45.0
var camera = MGLMapCamera()
let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 49.7484405,
                                        longitude: -132.9856644)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    mapView.mapType = .Standard

    camera = MGLMapCamera(lookingAtCenterCoordinate: coordinate,
                         fromDistance: distance,
                         pitch: 0,
                         heading: 0)
    self.mapView.camera = camera
}
```

Comment: Just curious. In your case were you able to use just the object instantiation can then call it? Or did you need to create the camera object as well? p.s. I've worked on a few MapBox projects so if you have any other questions I might be able to answer them for you.

Comment: I needed to create the camera object. If you have some spare time, I would really appreciate you taking a look at [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39050098/need-help-recreating-this-mapbox-effect). I am trying to create the effect described here for a fitness app. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

pitch is part of the `MGLMapCamera` class.

See

- https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/blob/ios-v3.3.4/platform/darwin/src/MGLMapCamera.h#L25
- https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.3.4/Classes/MGLMapCamera.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLMapCamera(py)pitch

And this sample snippet

```
/**
 Pitch toward the horizon measured in degrees, with 0 degrees resulting in a
 two-dimensional map.
 */
```

---

```
func togglePitch(sender: UISwitch)  {
    let camera = mapView!.camera
    camera.pitch = sender.on ? 60 : 0
    mapView!.setCamera(camera, animated: false)
}
```